# x11 forwarding through Google Colab

Tags: linux, ipython, google-colaboratory, x11-forwarding

I was hoping to get x11 forwarding to work on Google Colab. I am using a Windows 10 machine and the Google Colab OS information can be found at the bottom of the post. Here's what I did to test it out:

1. Installed [Xming](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) and ran it.
2. Made a new IPython notebook in Google Colab and installed x11 apps successfully using

   ```
   !sudo apt-get install x11-apps
   ```
3. Set my display to be my IP address using

   ```
   !export DISPLAY=<my-ip-address>
   ```
4. Run `!xeyes`. I get an error message saying `Error: Can't open display:`

I'm not sure if this is a problem of using the correct DISPLAY setting, running x11 forwarding through Google Colab or both!Can anyone help me out? Thank you!

The relevant parts of the output of when I run `!cat /etc/os-release` on my Google Colab notebook.

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
VERSION_ID="18.04"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Comment: Hi Rajiv, 
welcome to stack overflow! Your question already contains a lot of information. However, it will still be really hard for contributors to help you, as a basic example is missing. What OS are you running on? Where is Google Colab running? Whats your general setup? Provide a few more details, then maybe someone can help you :)

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian, I've added the info!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### tl;dr

1. Open 6000/tcp port on your router and firewall
2. Install VcXsrv
3. Run "XLaunch" with "Disable access control"
4. Run "!apt-get install x11-apps && export DISPLAY=YOUR_IP_ADDRESS:0.0 && eyes" on Colab

[image]

### Check

1. Google Colab does not keep environment variables across code cells. So you should set DISPLAY variable each them.

[image: Google Colab does not keep environment variables across code cells]

2. Xming may disallow remote connection as a default setting. At least, VcXsrv do that. Try to disable access control. This is an insecure option.

[image]

3. Router and firewall must open 6000+n/tcp port. The n is display number counting from 0. (e.g. HOSTNAME:0.0 → n=0)
   [Open Port Check Tool - Test Port Forwarding on Your Router](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/)
   [image]