# How can I use display functions on google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, xvfb

Im trying to use some display functions in a c++ code of mine. These functions would open up a window and display some image as an output there. How can i replicate this in google colab ?

Answer (score 0):

Colab cannot run C++. Only Python.

In Python, you don't display matplotlib in a new window, just in another cell.

Answer (score 0):

Google colab is capable of running C/C++ with Cuda.
this needs a very simple configuration first.

first, you need to do these instructions step by step `https://www.wikihow.com/Run-CUDA-C-or-C%2B%2B-on-Jupyter-(Google-Colab)`

Then you should figure out about x11 forwarding using this instruction `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60921979/x11-forwarding-through-google-colab`